# Unable to download offline address book in outlook 2007

Tags: windows-xp, exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2007.When I try to download the offline address book I am getting the following error message:

```
14:04:15 Microsoft Exchange offline address book
14:04:15 Not downloading offline address book files. A server (URL) could not be located.
14:04:15 0X8004010F
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of Exchange? If 2007, are your Autodiscover settings correct?

Comment: Exchange version is 2003

Comment: you just tagged this [exchange-2007], contradicting your above comment. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

[This MS site/tool](https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/) was a huge help to me in diagnosing Autodiscover issues.  If you run the tool against a test account, you should get some information in the error to narrow down your issue.